# How to stop a running method before it finish in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Hello i am new in android, i have a problem when i develop my application.

I have a modal with timer and close button. When the timer is over , the modal will close, or close the modal before the timer is over with close button. Here the picture : 
[image]

But the problem when i close the modal manually with press the close button, the method that run timer is still running and tried to close the modal although the modal is already closed , this is caused my application crashed. The error is

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null
>   object reference

How can i stop the method when i press close button?

Here my timer method to close modal when the timer is over :

```
public void startTimer(){
        int hoursToGo = 0;
        int minutesToGo = 0;
        int secondsToGo = 10;

    int millisToGo = secondsToGo*1000+minutesToGo*1000*60+hoursToGo*1000*60*60;

    new CountDownTimer(millisToGo,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millis) {
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000) % 60 ;
            int minutes = (int) ((millis / (1000*60)) % 60);
            String text = String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds);
            tv.setText(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("Request Timeout");
        }
    }.start();

    final AlertDialog d = (AlertDialog) getDialog();
    final Timer timer2 = new Timer();
    timer2.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            d.dismiss();
            timer2.cancel(); //this will cancel the timer of the system

            Intent i =  new Intent(getActivity(), PromoActivity.class);
            i.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(i,0);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

i execute the method in here :

```
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: Are you using getPackageName() method anywhere in your code ? If yes, please upload that code too. If not, please tell which line this NullPointerException is pointing to which will be mentioned in next line of your crash log.

Comment: at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
                                                                          at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4667)
                                                                          at com.sharpcs2.android.ui.fragment.BarcodeModalFragment$3.run(BarcodeModalFragment.java:151)
                                                                          at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Comment: BarcodeModalFragment‌​.java:151 is :

Intent i =  new Intent(getActivity(), PromoActivity.class);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `timer2.cancel();` when you press the close button

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps :

Assign the `CountDownTimer` instance to a variable, e.g.

```
CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(millisToGo,1000)
```

...then when you want to stop it, call

```
cdt.cancel()
```

Not sure why you need another Timer instance, you should remove it and put that code in

```
CountDownTimer onFinish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference on your TimerTask and call myTimerTask.cancel() on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following instead of `getActivity()` for the NullPointerException you are getting i.e.

1. Create a class variable context and give it's value in onCreateView() of your fragment i.e.

   `Context context;` //class variable

   `context = getActivity();` //inside onCreateView()
2. `Intent i = new Intent(context, PromoActivity.class);`